# Utilizing Twilio with Filemaker 15

Tags: twilio, filemaker

Looking for the best way to deploy Twilio as a SMS send tool within a Filemaker script to notify of order status updates. Nothing too complex.   Has anyone successfully achieved this

Comment: Two seconds on Google finds examples including code. https://www.google.com/search?q=twilio+filemaker

Answer (score 0):

Twilio is API, try using it with "Insert from URL" and FileMaker Post, although the best way would be using one of the plugins, like free BaseElements, which has curl, proper get and post functions.